# checkbox to open a window

Tags: javascript, html, window

I want for a window to open depending on what is checked in a checkbox.  It should be either fb or twitter or both windows open if both are selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var checky = document.getElementById('twitter');

function doalert(checkboxElem) {
if (checky.checked)
{
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.myurl.com&     text=" + document.forms["frm1"]["fname"].value + "");
} 
else 
{
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fimages%2Fcrowd_support.jpg"); 

}
}
</script>   



<form name="frm1" action="select_demo.html" onsubmit="doalert(this)">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="twitter" name="twitter"  value="false">Twitter</label><label><input type="checkbox"  name="facebook"  value="">Facebook</label>
<br>
<textarea name="fname" cols="68" rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: browser won't let you open 2 windows at one time using `window.open`. Need separate events ...one window per event

Answer (score 0):

You need check whether the checkbox is checked or not inside the function like this. Outside the function, it will be unchecked always when the page will loads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doalert(checkboxElem) {
var checkytw = document.getElementById('twitter');
var checkyfb = document.getElementById('facebook');

if (checkytw.checked)
window.open("https://www.twitter.com");
if(checkyfb.checked)
window.open("http://www.facebook.com"); 

}

</script>   



<form name="frm1" action="select_demo.html" onsubmit="doalert(this)">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="twitter" name="twitter"      value="false">Twitter</label><label><input type="checkbox"  name="facebook"  id="facebook"  value="">Facebook</label>
<br>
<textarea name="fname" cols="68" rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @hermes have you checked the answer!!